# What tool outputs this format? Google Closure compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Looking at some javascript code on someone's website, I see this.

```
12: [function(t, e, n) {
        ...
    },{}]
```

And then elsewhere in the file, the function is called this way.

```
loader: [function(t, e, n) {
    ...
    t(12);
    ...
}, {}]
```

I assume function 12 is being injected into the function t.

What tool generates code like this?  The website functions very well, and I would like to use their ideas (but not their code) to improve my own website.

Comment: a javascript uglifier?

Comment: @evolutionxbox seems like the case.

Comment: An obfuscator won't change the structure.  And no human wrote this structure.

Comment: I don't think it's closure-compiler. I believe their parameter names are generally alphabetical starting with `a` when possible.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for the info.  I wonder what it is.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Their website works very smoothly.  I would like to use the same technology.

Comment: If you search at Google for this:  "loader: [function(t, e, n)"   You get a lot of matches.  Whatever this technology is, it gets used a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is New Relic stuff.  New Relic inserts code to assist them in monitoring.

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/i-captured-this-nreum-thingy-and-dont-know-what-it-does/13523

So it doesn't help me to make a smooth-running website like that of the website I'm looking at.  Unless New Relic identifying hotspots has that much effect.